# get yarn install to fix errors yarn check finds

Tags: yarnpkg

If `yarn check` finds a discrepancy, how do I get `yarn install` to fix it?

Background: I have yarn.lock and package.json checked in; when I install a new package, it works locally, but then when I install to a different NODE_MODULES target, `yarn install` doesn't seem to notice that the new dependency needs to be added, but `yarn check` sees it.

Indeed, I read that `yarn install` does the same check as `yarn check --integrity`, and the later command does not see the discrepancy (ie functions just like `yarn install`). The question is how to get `yarn install` to perform the same check as `yarn check` or otherwise get `yarn install` to notice what `yarn check` has (or would have) found.

Comment: Any luck with this 6 months later? I can't figure out how to resolve the many errors I see in my log when I run Yarn check

Comment: Not yet ... my current work around is just to give up and reinstall in a new node_modules directory if yarn check fails :(

Comment: There is `yarn install --check-files` but I'm not sure that does the deep checks you are looking for.

Answer (score 14):

Note that from [yarn check documentation](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/check) it says:

> The command yarn check has been historically buggy and undermaintained and, as such, has been deprecated and will be removed in Yarn 2.0. You should use `yarn install --check-files` instead.

For me, I usually just `yarn upgrade --latest` to upgrade dependencies to latest versions.

Comment: I wasn't looking to change the yarn.lock file; I want to install (just if) the installed node_modules are out of sync with package.json and/or yarn.lock. This was for a docker image with node_modules/ mounted.

Comment: With yarn check and autoclean so buggy. Why not stick with npm?

Comment: `yarn upgrade` and `yarn upgrade --latest` are no longer commands.

`yarn up` is the new upgrade command. It does not take a --latest parameter.

Answer (score 0):

run `npx yarn-deduplicate yarn.lock`
then `yarn install`
then `yarn check`
and resolve any remaining duplicates by hand